# NDS Homebrew: Multiple Animation Speeds for Sprites

Tags: c, devkitpro

I have been experimenting with the devkitARM toolchain for NDS homebrew recently. Something I would like better understand, however, is how to control sprite animation speeds. The only way I know of doing this is by 'counting frames'. For example, the following code could be placed into the "animate_simple" example included with devkitpro:

```
int main(void) {
    int frame = 0;
    ...
    while(1) {
    ...
        if(++frame > 9)
            frame = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is generally fine, but it ensures that all the animation initialized in the main loop runs at a set speed. How would I go about having two different sprites, each animating at different speeds? Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a separate frame counter for each sprite. For example, you can create a sprite struct:

```
typedef struct _Sprite Sprite;
struct _Sprite
{
    int frame;
    int count;
    int delay; /* handles the speed of animation */
    int limit;
};

// initialize all fields

void sprite_update(Sprite* s) 
{
    if ( ( s->count++ % s->delay ) == 0 ) )
    {
        if ( s->frame++ > s->limit ) s->frame = 0;
    }
}
```

Give `delay` small value for faster animation, and a larger value for slow animation.

Sample Usage:

```
Sprite my_spr, my_spr_2;

/* initialize the fields, or write some function for initializing them. */

my_spr.delay = 5; /* fast */
my_spr_2.delay = 10; /* slow */

/* < in Main Loop > */

while(1){
...
   sprite_update(&my_spr);
   sprite_update(&my_spr_2);
}
```

**Note:**
Since you are targeting only one platform, the best way to control animation speed is to monitor the frame rate ( or "counting frames" as you call it ). Good thing about programming for consoles is, you don't have to set *timed delays*. Since all console devices of the same model usually run at the same speed, so the animation speed you get on your machine ( or emulator ) will be the same everyone gets. Different Processors Speeds are a real headache when programming for the PC.